# Minix pkgin error

Tags: virtualbox, minix

Hi I am working on Minix. I installed it on VirtualBox.

Now I want to install to Minix some programs like vim, bash etc. However I've gor an error like below:

```
pkgin: Can't open database /usr/var/db/pkgin/pkgin.db: unable to open database file: No such file or directory.
```

I am searching on net but I couldnt find any useful link or sth.

How can I get over this issue?

Comment: Happened to me once, it was because I hadn't run `reboot` since the install completed. Hope that helps someone who googled it!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should remove the installation disk from VirtualBox after setup and shutdown. I had this problem and solve it by this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a local zone in Openindiana 151a8. Try this:

```
root@server:~# mkdir -p /var/db/pkgin
root@server:~# pkgin update
```